# Java Runtime DLL injection

Tags: java, dll, code-injection

I was wondering if there is a Java method for injecting code into a process during runtime.
The key term; in Java. I have found alot of references to this (the most useful being at [this website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20084/A-More-Complete-DLL-Injection-Solution-Using-Creat)). The problem is that that all the references I've found do not use Java, and hence are unfavorable for my current situation.

Could anyone help me out, and perhaps point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think your comment "I would prefer code to Copy + Paste (yes, I am that lazy)" is going to get you some downvotes. Otherwise valid question. Consider editing if you were just trying to be funny.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and why do you need to do this from Java?

Comment: DNA: I am trying to make a method that logs calls to Direct X or OpenGl, so as to get the dump of what is being rendered by one or both of the items listed. The reason for why I would like to do this in Java is because I have a relatively short time to finish it in, and I am more comfortable with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Java Native Interface to bind CreateRemoteThread() API to Java.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but it seems like it will work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The closest I know of is [System.loadLibrary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29). That method will load a library by name in a system dependent way.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to load the non java library you found using [Java Native Access](https://github.com/twall/jna). I don't really see a way you will be able to do this without calling native code so unless a some other java developer has already created a JNI or JNA wrapper you will probably have to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be about what I am looking for. I will do some digging into the methods it provides, but at a first glance, it looks very promising. So once again, Thanks!